# Fuzzy join Chinese data sets in r

Tags: r, join

I am trying to fuzzy join two data sets by company names. I only require 60% character match for matching the company names. The problems is that the company names are all Chinese characters. I tried using `difference_left_join` function in the `fuzzyjoin` package to join the data sets by company names, but it returns an error says `Error in v1 - v2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator`. Then I tried `levenshteinSim` function to try to find the percent match between company names but it doesn't seem to apply to Chinese characters. Is there any other way to fuzzy match the company names and join them together?

Comment: could you possibly include some data in your question? for each data set, if you did `dput(head(dataset,5))` and paste the output into your question, people may be more able to help.